# Django :: Validation Error in not displaying

Tags: python, html, django

recently I am validating a from using Django. But I am not getting validation error when i enter wrong inputs.

please provide some suggestion where I have done wrong.

Below are my sample codes for python and html,

> **Views.py**

```
def contact_page(request):

contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
context = {
    "title":"contact page",
    "content":"Welcome to Contact page",
    "form": contact_form
}

if contact_form.is_valid():
    print(contact_form.cleaned_data)

return render(request, "contact/view.html", context)
```

> **Forms.py**    // using django forms for creating a form

```
from django import forms
// creating a form having 3 fields fullname, email and content (for some message )

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
fullname = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "class":"form-control",
                    "placeholder" :"Your name "
                    }
                )
            )

email    = forms.EmailField(
            widget=forms.EmailInput(
                attrs={
                    "class":"form-control",
                    "placeholder" :"Your Email "
                    }
                )
            )
content  = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    "class":"form-control",
                    "placeholder":"Your text"
                    }
                )
            )

// form validation 

def clean_email(self):      
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    if not "gmail.com" in email:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email has to be gmail.com")
    return email
```

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Are you showing the errors anywhere?

Comment: Hi Daniel, actually I want to display that validation error message when user enters other emails except abc@gmail. For example if I enter abc@yahoo.com then it should throw error as Email has to be gmail.com

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. Where do you want that to show? Are you displaying the errors in the template? Please *post* the template.

Comment: yes Daniel, I have added that html template. please check it out.